# Swift 3 : AppDelegate does not conform to protocol GIDSignInDelegate

Tags: swift, swift3, google-signin

Now I'm trying to implement Google Login.
I followed like this : 
    https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift

But I got a error in AppDelegate.swift :

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate 
....
```

error :

> Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'

Help me.

Comment: @Anish 웃 : Thank you for your reply. But I've already set it up, but this error occur.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to implement these two methods of `GIDSignInDelegate` in your `AppDelegate`.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Error disappear!

Comment: great work, used delegates from google's documentation but they werent updated, perhaps google should update their documentation too. Thanks brother :)