# AppDelegate does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate' in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate with Firebase using their Google Accounts by integrating Google Sign-In into app.

Using:

- Swift 3
- Xcode 8
- Firebase 3.11.1

I have implemented the two methods of `GIDSignInDelegate` in AppDelegate

```
// Sign-in flow has finished and was succcesful if error is nil:
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){
if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}

guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                      accessToken: authentication.accessToken)



// Finished disconnecting user from the app succesfully if error is nil:
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                withError error: Error!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
}
```

yet I am still faced with the compile issue:

> AppDelegate does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'

[image]

Comment: According to the documentation the methods are called signIn not sign. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_delegate-p#pub-methods. Are they the same in the header file you have for GIDSignInDelegate?

Comment: @Grunt I have tried func sign()  and func signIn(). It didn't worked. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Comment: Go to the issue navigator (⌘4) and click on the disclosure triangle next to the error, it tells you which methods are missing.

Comment: @vadian Swift Compile Error: AppDelegate does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'

Comment: Yes, of course, look at the issue navigator, it shows you the missing methods.

Comment: @vadian I have already implemented the suggestion from issue navigator:

Protocol requires function ’sign(_:didSignInFor:withError:)’ with type ‘(GIDSignIn!, Error!) -> Void’

Comment: Then comment out the method,  retype it and use code completion. At least there is an inconsistency `Error` / `NSError`.

Comment: Thanks @vadian I've updated the `NSError` to `Error` and retyped it.  I use GIDSignInDelegate library for code completion. 
Still does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'. 
:(

Comment: and you tried the other way? rename `Error` to `NSError` see [Google Sign-In for iOS: <GIDSignInDelegate> Protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_delegate-p) and see here [Firebase Google Sign-In](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin)

Comment: @muescha Yes, I tried `Error` to `NSError`.

Comment: @ConsBulaquena Have you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299017/swift-3-appdelegate-does-not-conform-to-protocol-gidsignindelegate

Comment: is there any solution as i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you defined the methods of that protocol **outside** of the `AppDelegate` class, so they are just global functions, not methods.

You need to move them inside the `}` that closes `AppDelegate` (just above the first protocol method).

> **Tip**: if you select all of the code in that file and press `Ctrl+I` Xcode will reindent your code which may make it easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: No problem! Sometimes it's easier than it seems. :)

Comment: i am getting the same error and i have written the code in curly braces also